# Positive way to say Captive Audience

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I want to use ***captive audience*** in my sales copy but even though that phrase is exactly the meaning I am trying to convey, I want to avoid the word *captive* as it carries a negative connotation. Is there a 2 or 3 word phrase that has the same meaning but has a positive, or at least a neutral connotation?

Comment: How about "**had the audience in the palm of his hand**"?

Comment: Can you provide a sentence or two to demonstrate how you want the word to be used 'in action'?

Comment: This is a similar phrase to what I was planing to use... Google isn't thrilled about duplicate content: "improved results by creating a more captive audience"

Comment: 'a loyal audience' is one that has made a choice to stay with you.

Comment: An 'appreciative audience' has a positive denotation, but may still prefer to catch the last bus home.

Comment: In what way is the audience captive? Are they there for some purpose different from the purpose of your sales copy? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Captive audience* -- [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/captive+audience)

> a person or people who are unable to leave a place and are thus forced to listen to what is being said
> *The passengers on the plane were a captive audience.*

This is **usually** only applicable if your audience is unable to leave, even though they don't want to stay and watch.

But instead, consider ***captivated (audience)*** -- [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/captivated)

> Use the adjective *captivated* to describe someone who is utterly charmed by something.
>
> A captivated student is enthralled by her teacher's history lesson, and **a captivated audience is involved in every word spoken on stage during a play**.

Similarly, you can use synonyms of *captivated* as well. Examples: ***charmed, delighted, enthralled, entranced, enchanted***.